# JS: Can't remove created Element in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm dynamically creating an image via javascript like this:

```
var dragimg = null;
function createImage(g) {
    dragimg = document.createElement("img");
    dragimg.src = "link/to/image.png";
    dragimg.style.width = "50px";
    dragimg.style.position = "absolute";
    dragimg.style.zIndex = 100;
    $("body").prepend(dragimg);
}
```

After creating the Image, I want to remove it at some point by calling this function:

```
function removeImage() {
dragimg.remove();
}
```

This works well in Chrome, Firefox & Opera. However, it doesn't work in **Internet Explorer 11**.

I'd also like to point out I have an `document.onmousemove` function set which manipulates the left and top attribute of the created image when the mouse moves. This works well in all browsers - but I'm not sure if it has something to do with the remove-problem.

I've also tried to remove the image by `dragimg.parentNode.removeChild(dragimg)`, but same result.

Comment: If you're using jQuery, why not use it ?

Comment: @adeneo, you should give an example of *how to use jQuery*.

Comment: `dragimg = $('<img />', {src: 'link', css : {width: 50px}})`

Comment: but removeChild should work, if it doesn't, jQuery probably wont either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things other than the classic just-use-jquery answer:

1. `element.remove()` is not supported yet by Internet Explorer, according to the API: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772117(v=vs.85).aspx. It's an experimental technology: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode.remove
2. Are you sure `parentNode.removeChild` isn't working because it is for me: http://jsfiddle.net/limdauto/wztm1dgk/

**Before**
[image]

**After**
[image]

Comment: What does not work? But, no, he shouldn't mind using jQuery again. It's just that removeChild doesn't work is a little hard to believe. And he said IE11, yes?

Comment: Wow, this is really weird! I swear I did exactly this yesterday and it didn't work... I guess it was a cache bug, although I cleared my cache after every change... :/ Thanks anyways, it's working now!

Answer (score 1):

To use jQuery `remove` method you need this:

```
function removeImage() {
    $(dragimg).remove();
}
```

Your `dragimg` is a dom element, but `$(dragimg)` is a jQuery element. While jQuery `prepend` method accepts dom elements, `remove` does not - it applies to jQuery element itself or to selector. More about [jQuery remove](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) and [prepend](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the context where you are calling the `removeImage` function, but the code below demonstrates inserting the image element and removes it after an interval of 2 seconds.

Note: Replace the path to your image.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var dragimg = null;
        function createImage(g) {
            dragimg = document.createElement("img");
            dragimg.src = "someimage.jpg";
            dragimg.style.width = "50px";
            dragimg.style.position = "absolute";
            dragimg.style.zIndex = 100;
            $("body").prepend(dragimg);
        }

        function removeImg() {
            dragimg.parentNode.removeChild(dragimg);
        }

        createImage(null);
        window.setInterval(removeImg, 2000);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please explain why the answer is downvoted so I can fix it?

Comment: I haven't downvoted it, but just tested it and it does not work in IE (I explained above).

Comment: remove() is not supported by IE